# Windows 10 cmd Environment Variable executable

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, windows-10

I'm trying to create an environment variable for my cmd so that I can launch Notepad++ without having to type in the full path.

I created an environment variable called NPAD which holds the directory where my Notepad++ executable is saved.

```
echo %NPAD%
C:\PROG\Resources\Notepad++
```

the shortcut that launches it is called npedit.lnk

When I try to execute it I have to type

```
%NPAD%\npedit.lnk
```

Is there a way to make it run just by using

```
npedit.lnk
```

Without directly using the NPAD environment variable, for example I can use java with just

```
java
```

Comment: `npedit.lnk` has to be in your `%path`% to work like `java`. Also `set "npad=C:\PROG\Resources\Notepad++\npedit.lnk"` may be an option. I personally have a batchfile `n+.bat` within my path with just one line:  `@"C:\PortableApps\Notepad++Portable\notepad++.exe" %*`

Comment: This was really helpful, would you mind posting these options as an answer, the batch file was my favorite of the options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Java` works, because it's in your `%path%`. To work `npedit.lnk` like this, you either have to put it into a folder defined by your `%path%` variable or add the directory of `npedit.lnk` to the `%path%` variable.

But you have more Options:

```
set "npad=C:\PROG\Resources\Notepad++\npedit.lnk"
```

(`setx npad C:\PROG\Resources\Notepad++\npedit.lnk"` for a permanent setting)

or (I use this) a batchfile (for example) `n+.bat` within the `%path%` with just one line:

```
@"C:\PortableApps\Notepad++Portable\notepad++.exe" %*
```

(adapt the path to your settings).

`%*` routes any parameters to Notepad++, so you can just type `n+ myfile.bat` to edit a specific file.